# Why Hadoop "MV" commands does not have FORCE option

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I want to move files between different HDFS folder. In some cases the destination folder contains a file with same name as source. I'm surprised to that there is no -f --force option. Any reason why force is not supported. Thanks.

hdfs dfs -mv SRC DEST

However I have a backup where solution where I remove the existing file and then perform a move.